# Unable To Show Data in PHP Using ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: php, asp.net, arrays, web-services

I've created a simple web service in `ASP.NET` and want that service to be consumed in a `PHP` application. The web service is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public List<Customer> GetCustomers(int id)
{
   id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"]);

   List<Customer> lst = null;
   using (var context = new DemoEntities())
   {
      lst = (from c in context.Customer
             where c.CustomerID == id
             select c).ToList();
   }

   return lst;
}
```

In the above web service, a customer id is passed to retrieve customer details. So to consume this service in `PHP`, I've tried to do the following using `nuSoap` library as follows and it works almost:

```
<?php
    require_once("lib/nusoap.php"); //Using the nuSoap library

    $client   = new nuSoap_Client('http://localhost:1284/MyCustomers.asmx?wsdl', TRUE); //Passed the ASP.NET web service and an object created
    $result = $client->call('GetCustomers', array('id' => 1)); //Called the GetCustomers method and passed a default parameter

    foreach($result as $item) //Tried to iterate in a foreach loop
    {
      echo $item; //Here is the issue - The output returns or returned only the name 'Array'  
    }
?>
```

I've done `PHP` programming a long time ago and trying to figure the issue searching google. I've even tried to access the array index with the web service property directly like the below but seems like missing something or may be not the correct way: Any idea would be appreciated

```
echo $item[1]->CustName;
echo $item[1]; //Even this
```

Right now, I am getting the `Xml` data as follows using the **Soap** web service:

```
<ArrayOfCustomer>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
    <CustName>John</CustName>
    <CustAddress>On Earth</CustAddress>
    <CustLocation>On Earth</CustLocation>
    <CustSex>Male</CustSex>
    <CustType>3</CustType>
    <CustStatus>2</CustStatus>
    <CustDetails>Great guy - Always regular.</CustDetails>
  </Customer>
</ArrayOfCustomer>
```

**Update 1**: Used `var_dump($item)` and currently getting the array elements as follows:

```
array
  'Customer' => 
    array
      'CustomerID' => string '2' (length=1)
      'CustName' => string 'John' (length=7)
      'CustAddress' => string 'On Earth' (length=25)
      'CustLocation' => string 'On Earth' (length=10)
      'CustSex' => string 'Male' (length=4)
      'CustType' => string '3' (length=1)
      'CustStatus' => string '2' (length=1)
      'CustDetails' => string 'Great guy - Always regular.' (length=47)
```

But when tried with this `$item->Customer->CustName`, getting this error again - **Trying to get property of non-object**.

**Update 2**: Again used `var_dump($item)` and the result is as follows with `PHP` programming:

```
<?php
    require_once("lib/nusoap.php"); 

    $client   = new nuSoap_Client('http://localhost:1284/MyCustomers.asmx?wsdl', TRUE);
    $result = $client->call('GetAllCustomers'); //Without any parameter
    foreach($result as $item)
    {
       echo var_dump($item);
    }
?>
```

**Output**:

```
array
  'Customer' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'CustomerID' => string '1' (length=1)
          'CustName' => string 'Jack' (length=7)
          'CustAddress' => string 'On Earth' (length=25)
          'CustLocation' => string 'On Earth' (length=10)
          'CustSex' => string 'Male' (length=4)
          'CustType' => string '3' (length=1)
          'CustStatus' => string '2' (length=1)
          'CustDetails' => string 'Regular Customer and always happy to cooperate.' (length=47)
      1 => 
        array
          'CustomerID' => string '2' (length=1)
          'CustName' => string 'John' (length=4)
          'CustAddress' => string 'On Earth' (length=7)
          'CustLocation' => string 'On Earth' (length=10)
          'CustSex' => string 'Male' (length=4)
          'CustType' => string '3' (length=1)
          'CustStatus' => string '2' (length=1)
          'CustDetails' => string 'Great guy - Always regular.' (length=25)
```

Again, tried to use two loops to get the values that's as follows but it only returns first two results and there are total 10 records in the database:

```
<?php
    require_once("lib/nusoap.php"); 

    $client   = new nuSoap_Client('http://localhost:1284/MyCustomers.asmx?wsdl', TRUE);
    $result = $client->call('GetAllCustomers');
    $count = count($result);

    foreach($result as $item)
    {
      for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
      {
         echo 'Name: ' . $item['Customer'][$i]['CustName'].'<br/>';
      } 
    }
?>
```

**Output**:

```
Name: Jack //Returns only first two records though it should return all the records
Name: John
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do a `var_dump($item);` in php to see how they array structure is.. currently I do not know what the response object is, but for example you can access the keys as such: `echo $item->Customer->CustName;`

If it is an array response, not an object, then: `$item['Customer']['CustName'];`

Comment: I am able to see the array elements using `var_dump($item)` but when tried with this `$item->Customer->CustName`, getting this error again - **Trying to get property of non-object**. Thanks for the quick suggestion. See my updated post.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot and worked perfectly. Learned a lot of things :)

Comment: I've one last issue @Amjo. Suppose, I've one web service without any parameter something like this from `$result = $client->call('GetCustomers', array('id' => 2));` to `$result = $client->call('GetAllCustomers', array('', ''));`. When I try to access, it again outputs **Array**. What would be the best way to get it done?

Comment: Again, what is the var_dump result? I must admit, I do not know asp in order to know what your GetCustomers method SHOULD return. So I need to rely on your response dump :(

Comment: But I do think if you do not send an id to that method, u might get your asp variable id to be empty. So your query might crash. Try to see what your query string becomes, before you execute the query in Your asp method

Comment: Again, I dont know asp and how it handles queries or how strict declaration of variables arek however, I do believe you should handle a case or an exception if id is not defined before just executing the query

Comment: Never mind for the late reply. I've updated the post and nearly made it work. Please check when you are free and let me know your valuable suggestions or any better way to do the above. Thanks for the replies.